# Can't run mysql request

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I need to select products (their names) and prices records that have an above average price, **but cheaper than 33**

My request:

```
select ProductName, Price
from Products
where Price>(select avg(Price) from Products)
and
Where Price < 33;
```

It's not working. Why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Not working" doesn't help much. Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the duplicate `where` like so:

```
select ProductName, Price
from Products
where Price > (select avg(Price) from Products)
   and Price < 33;
```